# Send mail not working in PHP

Tags: php, email

I create a functionality for user to send mail to their friends but mail is not sending. I have tried lots of example from the internet but it's not working. I request to my hosting provider but they are telling its my side issue, but I don't know what issue is

Here is my simple code :

```
$to      = 'example@gmail.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

$mail = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
if($mail){
echo "yes";
}
else{
echo "no";
}
```

Comment: add error_reporting(); on top and check error and post here.

Comment: its not giving any error